# ruby - activerecord fast import

Tags: ruby, activerecord

How the `active record fast import` works?

I want to import data from a file to database table.

How can I import data from a .csv file to database using fast_import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about reading [readme](https://github.com/jsuchal/activerecord-fast-import) on the project's github page? It has answers for all your questions:)